# How to break when a for loop reaches NSNotFound from a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I have a nsmutablearray which I add object to it in a for loop from a nsarray. I want it to add object until it reaches `NSNotFound` in indexOfObject: from NSArray. 
The array is inside a for loop to extract string from every index.

My code:

```
NSInteger untilNotFound = NSNotFound;
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObject:string];

for (index; index < untilNotFound; index ++)
{           
    [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex: index]];
}
```

---

Edit:

```
for (string in array)
{
NSComparisonResult *result = [string compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) 
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

if (result == NSOrderedSame)
{
            NSInteger index;
            for (index =[array indexOfObject:string]; (index < [array count] && index < 100 && index!= NSNotFound); index ++)
            {
                [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex: index]];         

            }

break;

}

}
```

---

EDIT.

My previous code that works, it is inside if (result == NSOrderedSame) I just wonder if there is any nicer and easier and performance-friendly solution to extract indexes just before it reaches NSNotFound:

```
        NSUInteger new = [array indexOfObject:string];

        NSString *last = [array lastObject];

        NSUInteger total = [array indexOfObject:last];

        NSUInteger newmax = new + 10;

        NSUInteger totalminus = total - 11;


        if (newmax <= totalminus )

        {

            [self.mutablearray addObject:string];

            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 1]];

            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 2]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 3]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 4]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 5]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 6]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 7]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 8]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 9]];
            [self.mutablearray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:new + 10]];
        }

        else 
        {
            [self.mutablearray addObject:string];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do a cumulative subset. Try this:

```
for(NSInteger index = [array indexOfObject: string]; ((index <  [array count]) &&
                                                      (index <= 100)           &&
                                                      (index != NSNotFound))   ;  index++)
{
    [self.mutablearray addObject: [array objectAtIndex: index]];
}
```

Or, if you're just doing a strict subset, try this:

```
NSInteger startIndex = [array indexOfObject: string];
NSInteger endIndex = MIN([array count], 100);
if(startIndex != NSNotFound)
{
    self.mutablearray = [array subarrayWithRange: NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)] mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: your answer is close to perfect, but I forgot to mention that I want to add 100 objects or less until the end of the array. How to do it?

Comment: So, you want to add no more than 100 elements, or the rest of the array if it's under 100 elements?

Comment: I havent tried it yet, but do you think it works with `for (index; index < index + 100 || index < index == NSNotFound; index ++)`

Comment: I added a 100 element cap, and a check to make sure than index doesn't start at NSNotFound.

Comment: Umm... it showed either 100 or nothing... I have a break; below this for a loop.

Comment: I tried also commenting out "break;", but it changes nothing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4508/discussion-between-patrick-perini-and-wagashi)

Comment: Your second code works with 100, but the app crashes whenever it is under 100 objects.

Comment: I changed it to `for (index ; (index < [array count] && index <= index + 100 && index!= NSNotFound); index ++)` Finally, it works as I wish! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

That's not how `NSArray` or `NSNotFound` work.  Attempting to access an object past the end of an `NSArray` will raise an exception.  Is there a specific reason why you want to do it this way?  It's much easier to use fast enumeration:

```
for (id object in array) {
    [self.mutablearray addObject:object];
}
```

**Edit:** I see from your other comments that you want to limit this to a maximum of 100 objects added to the mutable array.  That's easy enough:

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (id object in array) {
    [self.mutablearray addObject:object];
    count++;
    if (count >= 100) break;
}
```

Comment: But it raises an exception when it is within 100 indexes from nsarray.

Comment: it doesnt work. it shows only when i enter first alphabet in searchtext, more than that, nothing shows.

Comment: I thought it would raise an exception, but it didnt. it just display the result when I enter the first alphabet, and after that, nothing changes in the result list which is self.mutablearray. Please tell me where I should put this code? I tried this code inside if (result == NSOrderedSame).

Comment: It's impossible to debug your code without more information about what it is you are doing.  You talk about "after you enter the first alphabet", but there's no description of that in your question.  Try explaining exactly what it is you are trying to achieve, from a functional point of view.

Comment: please see my detailed code below my question. searchText is the text field which the user enters to search a word. It should display the result list immediately for each alphabet. Is it more clear now? I just want to break the main loop after 100 objects or less are extracted to save the performance.

Comment: You're keeping hold of `mutablearray` in a property.  Every time you search for something, the old results are going to appear because you aren't clearing it out.  Do you actually need this to be a property?  Will a local variable work instead?

Comment: I need it as a property, because it is required in UITableView and other methods too. Please see my new edit.

Comment: When a new search is performed, you need to call `removeAllObjects` on `self.mutablearray` and then after you've filled it in again, you need to call `reloadData` on the table view.

Comment: Both are already existant. removeAllObjects is in the last line before the main for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I found a solution now.

Answer (score 1):

NSNotFound is defined like this

```
enum {NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax};
```

so you're going to be accessing invalid indeces in your array.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new, but do you have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id obj in array){
 [self.mutableArray addObject:obj];
}
```

This will run until array has objects.